# Unity+VisualStudio: C# code disassembly unavailable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, unity-game-engine

I'd like to be able to see the disassembly for Unity c# programs just the same as with non Unity c# programs.

In Visual Studio, I tried putting Visual Studio in "Debug" solution configuration and enabling "Tools / Options / Debugging / General / Enable address-level debugging and Show disassembly if source is not available", then I click the "Attach to Unity" button, put down a breakpoint in my Unity c# code. Visual Studio stops at the chosen line of code, I can get all the usual info by hovering variables or using the Watch debug window.

At that point everything seems like if I was debugging a regular non Unity c# program, however, if I go to "Debug / Windows / Disassembly", I get the message "No disassembly available." .

I'd like to instead be able to view the disassembly, anyone have an idea how?

Comment: I don't know the VS settings but you could use [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) which adds this automatically

Comment: Doesn't ReSharper add C# disassembly only? I am hoping to find how to see the assembler disassembly...